# Schema.org hierarchy as XML

Tags: xml, schema.org

I am intersted in using the Schema.org hierarchy to help users define "things" that they add to my custom CMS.
For example if they wanted to add a "person" to my CMS, they would have to add all the fields from [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) and [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person).

I am looking for an XML document or some other document that I can parse to generate the hierarchy of required fields.

A tree of elements with their fields and data types would be perfect.

Basically I am looking for this entire document in XML format or some other computer readable format (JSON, ect.): http://schema.org/docs/full.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [schema.rdfs.org](http://schema.rdfs.org/) - pertinent links:

- [RDF/XML](http://schema.rdfs.org/all.rdf)
- [JSON](http://schema.rdfs.org/all.json)
- [CSV](http://schema.rdfs.org/all-properties.csv)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity how did you find this?

Comment: Linked from "External Resources" at the [schema.org Documentation](http://schema.org/docs/documents.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing [Schema.org for Developers](https://schema.org/docs/developers.html), more specifically the [Vocabulary Definition Files](https://schema.org/docs/developers.html#defs), we will be able to download according to one's preferences:

- `JSON-LD`
- `Turtle`
- `Triples`
- `Quads`
- `RDF/XML`
- `CSV`

The one you are looking for is in the format `RDF/XML` and, assuming you want too keep the retired terms, here is the direct link: https://schema.org/version/latest/schemaorg-all-https.rdf

[image]

If you don't want the retired terms, then this is the link you should go: https://schema.org/version/latest/schemaorg-current-https.rdf

[image]

If you have any issues, [here is the GitHub repo](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg).

If one wants to know how they develop and change schemas, go here: https://schema.org/docs/howwework.html

Answer (score 0):

The [canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581346/1591669), machine-readable representation of Schema.org is in **HTML+RDFa**:

**http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html**

Each Schema.org release (starting from [2.0](http://schema.org/version/2.0/)) is available as a frozen snapshot in HTML+RDFa ([example for 2.0](http://schema.org/version/2.0/schema.rdfa)) and in N-Triples ([example for 2.0](http://schema.org/version/2.0/schema.nt)).

An [experimental JSON(-LD) version](http://schema.org/docs/tree.jsonld), and an [obsolete RDF/XML snapshot](http://schema.org/docs/schemaorg.owl) are available, too.